# Clojure ^floats vs. #^floats?

Tags: clojure

What is the difference between `^floats` and `#^floats` in Clojure type annotations?

In a pull request, someone suggested I use this annotation:

```
(.put #^floats init-fft-array)
```

which did the trick, but I don't know why the '#' is there.  I found this worked, too:

```
(.put ^floats init-fft-array)
```

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`#^floats` is a legacy syntax, with newer Clojure versions `^floats` is preferred.

Comment: That explains why I can't find any mention of the `#^` combination anywhere in the [macro characters documentation](http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Macro%20characters).

Comment: I'll accept @noisesmith's response, but if anyone has a historical link to show when the legacy syntax changed, that would be nice to see.

Comment: @RogerAllen - I was wondering the same thing, so I did some digging. I was going post a reply here, but it was too long for a comment, and didn't make sense as an answer here (since it's actually a new question). I decided to self-answer the new question here instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445465/