# When did the metadata reader syntax change from #^ to ^?

Tags: clojure

Currently (Clojure v1.6) you can give a type hint two ways:

```
^floats xs
```

```
#^floats xs
```

According to *[Clojure ^floats vs. #^floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30429749/1427124)*, the latter is legacy syntax, and the former is the current preferred form.

When did that change happen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## A brief history of the `^` macro character

- In Clojure v1.0, the `^` character is the "meta reader macro". In other words, `^x` was shorthand for `(meta x)`. `#^` was used to associate metadata with an object. (See the [Macro Characters documentation from November 2009](https://web.archive.org/web/20091129075556/http://clojure.org/reader#toc2).)
- At some point, someone probably realized that having special cases for both `#^` and `^`, both related to metadata, was confusing. [They decided to deprecate `^`](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-215), with the plan to eventually replace `#^` with `^`. In Clojure v1.1, the `^` reader macro [was officially deprecated](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure/blob/1.1.x/changes.txt#L53-L56). (See the [Macro Characters documentation from January 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20100126125635/http://clojure.org/reader#toc2).)
- There's [a commit on April 26, 2010 on Github](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/a5ca8243e3ea45e6387b2b00d0e9b2624d16adbf) that replaces the old `^` behavior with the `#^` behavior. (This is when `#^` and `^` became synonymous.)
- In the Clojure v1.2 release, [`#^` was deprecated in favor of `^`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/1.2.x/changes.txt#L89-L92). (See the [Macro Characters documentation from August 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20100806055359/http://clojure.org/Reader#The%20Reader--Macro%20characters).)
- They [removed the last few instances of `#^` from clojure.core](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1072) back in 2013, sometime before the Clojure v1.6 release.